# Is there a way to use DesiredCapabilities for getting a non-remote browser in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver, httpbrowsercapabilities

In Seleneium one can easily create WebDriver objects by either creating them directly

`driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

or be using DesiredCapabilities with a remote web driver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("something"), capabilities);
```

What I am looking for is using desiredcapabilties for creating local driver objects. Something like:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver = WebDriver.getDriver(capabilities);
```

I think it is impossible. Any insights on this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Depending on the scenario I want to either use local browsers (without starting a selenium server) or remote browsers. For both conditions I want to use the same desiredcapabilities to fetch a matching browser (if possible).

Answer (score 3):

You can just do the following:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But this would only create Firefox instances, right. Using `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()` with the FirefoxDriver constructor will fail. I want an arbitrary driver constructor that really starts the browser locally but only dependent of the DesiredCapabilities object.

Comment: Each driver object class initializes the Browser locally internally. As of now you cannot just use the capabilities for starting the server automatically. You have to atleast start the server locally and can run the test by creating a driver object using RemoteWebDriver class with capability as argument.

Comment: Whoever uses this, make sure you try it out, coz I have tested this and it didn't work to disable JavaScript - only creating a `FirefoxProfile` worked.